# Downloading gz json file from url in R

Tags: r

```
lien_du_cadastre<-str_replace_all(paste("https://france-cadastre.fr/cadastre/",Nom_ville), " ","")
lien_du_cadastre
serveur_objet$navigate(lien_du_cadastre)

url2=serveur_objet$findElement(using = 'xpath','/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[1]')$getElementAttribute("href")[[1]] #donne l'url de téléchargement du plan cadastre
url2 (the url inside is : https://france-cadastre.fr/downloadcenter.php?format=json&echelle=commune&insee=02408&type=parcelles)
file_path <- tempfile(pattern = "", fileext = ".json")
file_path
download.file(url2, file_path, quiet = TRUE, mode = "wb")
```

Hi, I'm trying to download a file from this website after got the url but the file which is downloaded is corrupted because when i tried to open it i see binary and character not the json file content. I tried to download it manually and by this way the real content is displayed. I don't know my using of download.file function is bad  i didn't succeed to fixe it since.

Answer (score 0):

The `jsonlite` package has the `parse_gzjson_raw()` function to read gzip compressed data.  First you need to read the data into R as a raw vector.

```
library(jsonlite)

url <- "https://france-cadastre.fr/downloadcenter.php?format=json&echelle=commune&insee=02408&type=parcelles"

dat <- readBin(url, "raw", 1e07)  # Or readr::read_file_raw(url)
res <- parse_gzjson_raw(dat)
```

Check the data:

```
str(res)

List of 2
 $ type    : chr "FeatureCollection"
 $ features:'data.frame':   12405 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ type      : chr [1:12405] "Feature" "Feature" "Feature" "Feature" ...
  ..$ id        : chr [1:12405] "02408000AB0133" "02408000AB0132" "02408000AB0131" "02408000AB0129" ...
  ..$ geometry  :'data.frame':  12405 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ type       : chr [1:12405] "Polygon" "Polygon" "Polygon" "Polygon" ...
  .. ..$ coordinates:List of 12405
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:12, 1:2] 3.63 3.63 3.63 3.62 3.63 ...
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:9, 1:2] 3.63 3.62 3.62 3.62 3.62 ...
  .. .. ..$ : num [1, 1:17, 1:2] 3.62 3.62 3.62 3.62 3.62 ...
...
```